# Does OS X log my IP address?

Tags: macos, logging, ip-address

I need to know which IP address I was using two days ago. Is there any log file in OS X that contains this information?

**Update**: And Chrome for Mac could store this information somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find previous IP addresses my ISP assigned me?](http://superuser.com/questions/175172/how-can-i-find-previous-ip-addresses-my-isp-assigned-me)

Comment: I had checked that post, but it doesn´t help. Gmail emails don´t store any more IP information

Comment: @user2082695 [I added an answer](http://superuser.com/a/750081/68111) on that to that question which may be useful to you.

Comment: I knew about that, I tried, but the information was going only one day back, so not enough

Answer (score 2):

It's too late for you now, but you can get it to start logging things like this by running…

```
sudo ipconfig setverbose 1
```

…at every boot.

Then you can search for "network changed" in the All Messages ASL log stream in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`, or in `/var/log/system.log[.#.gz]`, or in `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/com.apple.networking.IPConfiguration.log.[SomeDateString[.gz]]`

Comment: Could you please add the path to where this gets logged?

Answer (score 0):

From the possible duplicate:

> Your modem/router might keep logs on which IP the DSL was registered
>   to. Usually the modem's logs/UI is accessible by navigating to its IP
>   through your browser.

My modem keeps a firewall log.  You may be able to look at your modem to find out source/destination addresses and see it there.

Comment: IN the logs of my modem-router there are no information about the IP.